# Portainer using the wrong location for volume uploads

Tags: docker, portainer

I'm using Portainer CE 2.18.3. My server has 2 disks:

- `/` - Operating system (8GB)
- `/srv/docker` - Docker (50GB)

I have changed Docker's data root as follows:

```
#/etc/docker/daemon.json 
{ 
   "data-root": "/srv/docker/images"
}
```

Everything works as expected.

I then create a volume through the Portainer UI - `test_volume`. Portainer shows the mount point as `/srv/docker/images/volumes/test_volume/_data`. I can see this folder exists on the server.

I then use Portainer's volume browse feature to upload a file called `test.txt`. I expect it to be saved in `/srv/docker/images/volumes/test_volume/_data/test.txt`.

However, it actually gets saved at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/test_volume/_data/test.txt` (i.e. the original Docker data-root location).

It seems as though Portainer is just ignoring the hosts Docker config. I can't see a way to change a relevant setting in Portainer.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I post the question....

https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/3617

It seems at the time of writing that Portainer has the volume location hard coded and ignores the host settings.